# Links in an iframe to change the parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink

iv been recently building a website that has a table embeded in an iframe, now if I click a link from the embeded table it opens in the iframe. On other forums I've heard everyone say all you need is to put `target="_parent"`, but it doesn't ever specify where to put it so I cant even test if it works

You can view a copy of my code [**here**](http://pastebin.com/KLbx4Exx).

I'm pretty sure that I need to change the following to make it work but I don't know what with

```
output.document.write(desc[itemp].bold() +"<br>" + links[itemp].link(links[itemp])+ "<br>");
```

Any Help would be great

Comment: Here is code on [**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/elajov/1) for anyone interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code relies on the fact that

```
'foo'.link('bar'); // "<a href="bar">foo</a>"
```

That method ([`String.prototype.link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link)) doesn't give you the option to change *target*, you'd have to do this manually

```
'<a href="' + links[itemp] + '" target="_parent">' + links[itemp] + '</a>'
```

Though this code is exceedingly old (copyright 1997), so you may be better off having the whole thing rewritten and or not using it as an example to learn from.

Comment: thanks man saved my ass, been looking at tis code for too long to redo it, but now its working ill start on a new set

Answer (score 0):

You just put it in the  tag as an attribute e.g. :

```
<a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target="_parent">BBC News</a>
```

Comment: So what would that be like with the info?

Would i just put it in "links[itemp].link(links[itemp])" or at the start of the text?